# Variables in SQL queries with PyQGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I want to create spatial indexes in all the tables that are included in a schema in PostGIS.
The layers remain the same but the schema is everytime different.
So I wanted to pass a variable var = schemaname + "l_abluft(geom)" to the SQL query (CREATE INDEX ON test.l_abluft(geom);)

```
#--Create a Connection to PostGIS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
connection = psycopg2.connect (dbname = "xxxxx",
                           user = "xxxxxx",
                           password = "xxxxx",
                           host = "xxxxxx",
                           )
cursor = connection.cursor()

#--Create spatial Indexes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON test.l_abluft(geom);")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON test.l_zuluft(geom);")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON test.rl_isolierung(geom);")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON test.treppenhaus(geom);")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON test.waende_saeule_usw(geom);")
connection.commit()
print("Query successful")
```

I tried the following but I got the error:
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX ON "test.l_abluft(geom)"

```
schemaname = "test"
var = schemaname + ".l_abluft(geom)"

#--Create spatial Indexes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL("CREATE INDEX ON {}").format(sql.Identifier(var)))
connection.commit()
print("Query successful")
```

Comment: I do something like this all the time, but it's just a simple string formatting issue with Python. Extract the parts that don't change and use `str.format()` or `str.replace()` to add the parts that do.

Comment: On a side note, you may want to use a [GIST index](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) (requires Python version >= 3.6) :

```py
#--Create a Connection to PostGIS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
connection = psycopg2.connect(dbname = "xxxxx",
                              user = "xxxxxx",
                              password = "xxxxx",
                              host = "xxxxxx",
                             )
cursor = connection.cursor()

#--Create spatial Indexes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
my_schema = "test"
cursor.execute(f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.l_abluft(geom);")
cursor.execute(f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.l_zuluft(geom);")
cursor.execute(f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.rl_isolierung(geom);")
cursor.execute(f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.treppenhaus(geom);")
cursor.execute(f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.waende_saeule_usw(geom);")
connection.commit()
print("Query successful")
```

For Python versions < 3.6 use :

```py
settings = {"my_schema": "test"}
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.l_abluft(geom);".format(**settings)
```

---

With Python 3.6, it will be cleaner (IMHO) to write code like this :

```py
#--Create a Connection to PostGIS
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
db_params = {
    "dbname": "xxxxx",
    "user" = "xxxxxx",
    "password" = "xxxxx",
    "host" = "xxxxxx",
}

my_schema = "test"
fields = [
    "l_abluft(geom)",
    "l_zuluft(geom)",
    "rl_isolierung(geom)",
    "treppenhaus(geom)",
]

with psycopg2.connect(**db_params) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        list(map(
            curs.execute,
            [f"CREATE INDEX ON {my_schema}.{fld};" for fld in fields]
        ))

print("Query successful")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works